# Six particles at the corners of a regular hexagon of side $a$ move at a constant speed $v$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

Each particle maintains a direction towards the particle at the next corner. Calculate the time the particles will take to meet each other.

When the particles move with same speed,how can they ever meet each other?Will someone clarify me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Time taken for collision](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/68648/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While they have the same speed, their velocity keeps changing direction so that one particle always moves towards one of the others. Now, as no particle is heading away in a straight line from any other particle, the relative velocity between any two particles is one that favours them to keep getting nearer. The hexagon formed by the particles will therefore 'rotate and shrink' over time.